# Default sign place at company sign field

Tags: docusignapi

I want to send documents to a signers like following:

[image]

Is it possible for the company to sign and use the DocuSign account default signature using a template?

Comment: Can you please share an example what you are trying to solve here, as it is not clear with these two lines.

Comment: I want to use Template of DocuSign.The only customer can sign this signature fields.company signature field use default signature of DocuSign id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raj,

Yes, it is possible to use templates with DocuSign.
See their [official documentation explanining how to use templates](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates)

Comment: I am currently using Docusign Template But I can't solve this issue.Can you provide me some sample Template.